# Laravel Forge sudo user asking for password

Tags: laravel, sudo, laravel-forge

I'm new to Laravel Forge so I'm still wrapping my head around how it works. I've connected to my Digital Ocean account and provisioned a new server which is up and running. I connected my Github account and I successfully pulled my files to the server. So, all is good on that front.

However, there's one nagging issue. When Laravel Forge sets up the server, they issue a sudo user of "forge" and a password. I can SSH into the server using ssh forge@xx.xx.xx.xx just fine. I do not need to enter a password to do this because I've put my id_rsa.pub into the Forge CP and into the Digital Ocean CP. But, when I try to sudo anything (eg. sudo rm), I'm prompted for my password. I'd like to avoid the step of having to provide my password when using sudo.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel Forge root access is restricted to prevent unintentional breaking of package dependencies as per the [docs](https://forge.laravel.com/docs/1.0/servers/provisioning-process.html#automated-security-updates).

> Security updates are automatically applied to your server on a weekly
> basis. Forge accomplishes this by enabling and configuring Ubuntu's
> automated security update service that is built in to the operating
> system.
>
> Forge does not automatically update other software such as PHP or
> MySQL automatically, as doing so could cause your server to suffer
> downtime if your application's code is not compatible with the
> upgrade. However, it is possible to install new versions and patch
> existing versions of PHP manually via the Forge UI.

Comment: The question's goal was "I'd like to avoid the step of having to provide my password when using sudo." Not sure how this answers that.

Comment: Thats the point. Sudo is not available. Security and package updates are automatically managed. The real question is what is the asker trying to achieve by SSH'ing in?

Comment: @miken32 `sudo` is available to the `forge` user. They are part of the sudo group. If you type `groups` while logged in as the `forge` user: `forge sudo www-group`. Even though it is rare, there are times when you will need to use `sudo` especially for installing packages or services that aren't directly managed by Forge. This is one of the bonuses to using Forge as a service, the server is still yours at the end of the day

Answer (score 0):

The execution of commands via `sudo` is a separate flow to SSH'ing into your server.

For example, even when you're using your local machine (assuming you're on a Mac or Linux OS), you still need to enter your password when issuing `sudo` commands. The same with the server (regardless if its Forge or anything else).

There are ways around this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/147241/execute-sudo-without-password
However, I would recommend leaving it on - if nothing else it acts an a reminder you may be doing something potentially risky.

Generally speaking, you don't need to SSH or `sudo` too often when using Forge.